# quarkus hot deploy without saving file

Tags: quarkus

I use hot deploy `./mvnw compile quarkus:dev`. According to the documentation, I do only need to change the files **without saving** it and refresh the browser. However, in my case hot deploy does only work if I **save the file before requesting the page**. I used the *getting-started*-project from quarkus quickstarts. My question is: Is this the right behaviour (*change file->save file->request page*) and the following statement wrong (*change file->request page*):

https://www.baeldung.com/quarkus-io (section 4: hot reload)

> In other words, changes made to Java files or to configuration files
>   will automatically be compiled once the browser is refreshed. The most
>   impressive feature here is that we don't need to save our files. This
>   could be good or bad, depending on our preference.

Comment: have you tried use a editor/IDE with autosave configuration?

Comment: I use eclipse ide. but the question is not about autosave..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely need to save your files for hot reload to be triggered.

The update is based on the file timestamps to have changed.

What you don't need is recompiling your application or restarting anything.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. The documentation is a little confusing..

Comment: Well, please report it to the author. This is not our official documentation.